# Render part of a webusercontrol in different location on content page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, webusercontrol

Given this webusercontrol:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Comments.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_Fresh_Comments" %>

Hello World!

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Javascript">
    <script>
        alert("Hello!");
    </script>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

And this on my master page:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="JSContent"/>
```

How can I make the `Javascript` content in the webusercontrol render into the `JSContent` content placeholder?

For good practise and performance, I wish to have control over where the Javascript is rendered on the page.  I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require me to modify anything outside of the webusercontrol.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh, just started a bounty then immediately figured it out for myself.  On the webusercontrol `Page_Load` add the lines:

```
Page.Master.FindControl("JSContent").Controls.Add(Javascript);
```